# Is there a way to query for how many times a user made changes to a TFS ticket?

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking at setting up a query in TFS that tells me how many times a user changed a particular TFS ticket. Is this a possibility in TFS2017 or even in **Power BI Desktop**?

For example, creating a query in TFS with the following added:

And - Changed By - Was Ever - Smith.John

gives all tickets "Smith.John" ever changed but doesn't tell me how many times he's made changes to them.

Example Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxvYi.jpg

From the image above, I'm looking for an answer of 4 (Smith.John changed the ticket 4 times) but it will only appear once in a query. I know this is likely not possible in TFS itself so I'm hopefully looking for a solution in Power BI Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to query for how many times a user made changes to a TFS ticket?

Indeed, it is not possible in TFS itself, all the results of the query are workitems list not the details of workitems.

There is a extension which using the TFS API, it could pull all history for one specify workitem:

[TFS SDK: Work Item History Visualizer using TFS API](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/08/21/tfs-sdk-work-item-history-visualizer-using-tfs-api.aspx)

[image]

If this extension does not meet your needs,you could use the API to output the workitem all changes history:

[TFS API: TFS Work Item All Changes History](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1117462/TFS-API-TFS-Work-Item-All-Changes-History)

Then export this grid in format you want and save it locally.

If all above are not what you want, you just want to use Power BI Desktop to resolve this issue, you can check following blog, it should give you some help:

[Querying the VSTS Work Items API directly from Power BI](https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/07/querying-the-vsts-work-items-api-directly-from-power-bi/)

Hope this helps.